# Selenium + C#: ExecuteAsyncScript not working

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I'm trying to run javascript through Selenium driver. The executeAsyncScript argument gives the exception that input string is not in correct format. 
The javascript is in the path provided. The javascript function is actually an onclick that does not take any parameters but returns a value that I want to get for further computation.

```
 Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
           var js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
     var formobject = js.ExecuteAsyncScript(
                           "var callback = arguments[0];"
                         + "var params = arguments;"
                         + "require(['Recruiting/Modules/CandidateProfile'],function(onPrint){"
                         + "onPrint("
                         + ",callback"
                         + ");});"
                     );
```

Comment: What is the comma before "callback" for? Shouldn't it say onPrint(callback)? I think you might have confused yourself with all the concatenations.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your javascript is *syntacticly incorrect*. If you would omit the quotes, you would get:

```
var callback = arguments[0];
var params = arguments;
require(['Recruiting/Modules/CandidateProfile'],function(onPrint){
onPrint(
,callback
);});
```

See the `,` after the `onPrint` and before the `callback`.